# How do I use jGoodies Form Layout with Netbeans 7

Tags: java, netbeans, jgoodies

I am using Java 1.6.0_29, with Ubuntu and Netbeans 7. I want to use the jGoodies Forms Layout with Netbeans. How do I get this working? I tried to add it as a layout manager for use with the builder GUI but I cannot seem to get it working.

Thanks...

Comment: @ Eric: Try to use java 1.7 version for netbeans 7.

Comment: Why? What will this do for me?

Comment: @ Eric: Sometimes Due to version compatibility, it may not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

download & install JFormDesigner - plugin from http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/39703/jformdesigner
JGoodies FormLayout
These well-known open-source layout managers allow you to design high quality forms. JFormDesigner provides excellent support for them.
easy to use this plugin for jgoodies forms

The API documentation is also available here: doc.formdev.com/jgoodies-forms/